# maxReceivedMessageSize How to Set in Asp.net Core Api?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I am running into a 400 error where it seems if my json post it too big it will error out.

I think it is related to `maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647"` Can I make this bigger and how in asp.net core 2.2? Web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hosting on IIS? If yes, then try setting `maxAllowedContentLength`

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#configuration)

Comment: Yes, I am hosting on iis.  What is the difference between maxRecivedMessageSize and maxAllowedContentLength?

Comment: I'm not sure what `maxReceivedMessageSize` is for. `maxAllowedContentLength` specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes. Basically, it limits how much data can sent in a single request to your app. The default value is 30000000 (or ~28.6MB).

Comment: @chobo2 did my idea solve your issue? If it did, can you accept and up-vote?